# Emulating a web page form POST submission through C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, http

I'm trying to write a C# script that in effect does the same thing as when I submit a form through the UI of a certain webpage. This is on a public page of a site that doesn't use cookies. I looked in Chrome at the Network tab for what happens in the request/response when I submit a comment
[image]

[image]

and I'm trying to emulate that in C# land:

```
                    CommentFormData data = CommentFormData.GenerateRandom();
                    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
                    StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8);
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Connection", ";eep-alive");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", json.Length.ToString());
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "...");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Origin", "...");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Referer", "...);
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Prototype-Version", "1.6.1");
                    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("...", content);
```

.....

```
internal class CommentFormData
{
    public string pageID { get; } = "...";
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int timezone { get; } = -7;

    public static CommentFormData GenerateRandom()
    {
        return new CommentFormData()
        {
            comment = GenerateRandomString(),
            author = GenerateRandomString(),
            email = $"{GenerateRandomString()}@gmail.com"
        };
    }

    private static string GenerateRandomString(int length = 100)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
}
```

I am getting back status code 200, but it's not working the same. The response I'm getting is

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Keep-Alive: timeout=20
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Date: Sat, 10 Jun 2017 20:44:36 GMT
  Server: nginx
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
}
```

so why isn't this working? Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be JSON encoding your data rather than form encoding that, is there a reason for that?

Comment: Does your serialization type for the request content match the Content-Type header?

Comment: @NickBailey No, and that's probably my problem. Let me see if that will fix it ...

Comment: @NickBailey, what do I put as key-value pairs? All the header stuff? And the body stuff too?

Comment: Use `FormUrlEncodedContent` instead of `StringContent` and pass list with form data to it's constructor. Also do not set `Host`, `Content-Type` and `Conten-Length` headers as they are set automatically.

Comment: What's your end goal?  Is it for testing or debugging a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the System.Net.Http.HttpsClient class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Use this calss to construct and execute requests asynchronously, and read the contents of their responses.